# Question on induced homomorphism involving translation maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm working with Viro's textbook on topology, and I stuck on this exercise on induced homomorphisms:
[image: exercise 36.F in Viro's textbook on topology]

Where $ T_s : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_1) : [\alpha] \mapsto [s^{-1}\alpha s] $ -- a translation map.

I picked an element $ [u] \in \pi_1(X,x_0) $ and applied given compositions in order to get the same result, but that's what I got:
$$ (f_* \circ T_s)[u] = [f \circ (s^{-1}us)] = [(f\circ s^{-1})(f\circ u)(f\circ s)] $$
$$ (T_{f\circ s} \circ f_*)[u] = T_{f\circ s}([f\circ u]) = [(f\circ s)^{-1} (f\circ u) (f\circ s)] $$

And I can't get further: either I made a mistake somewhere or I need to show that $ f\circ s^{-1} = (f\circ s)^{-1} $. I feel like this question is a bit silly and all, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: Seems all correct. $$(f\circ s)^{-1}(t) = (f\circ s)(1-t) = f(s(1-t)) = f(s^{-1}(t)) = (f\circ s^{-1})(t),$$no?

Comment: Yeah, I just was thinking inverse in the sense of maps, not paths

Comment: That's why I like writing $s^{\leftarrow}$ instead of $s^{-1}$, but this is a personal choice and I always explain what the notation means when I use it, since it's non-standard.

Comment: (so e.g. $[u]^{-1} = [u^{\leftarrow}]$ and so on)

Comment: Yeah, this notation seems better in this sense, probably I should consider using it, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the inverse here denotes inverse in the sense of paths, i.e. $s^{-1}(t) = s(-t)$. With this in mind, we have

$$(f\circ s)^{-1}(t) = (f\circ s)(-t) = f(s(-t)) = f(s^{-1}(t)) = (f\circ s^{-1})(t)$$

and hence $(f\circ s)^{-1} = f\circ s^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh, indeed! Thank you, this is clear as a day!